# Mysql update adding subquery field value to field

Tags: mysql, update

I want to update a field adding it the value of a subquery field.

I'm trying this:

```
UPDATE table a 
SET a.field=(a.field+b.subfield) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT subid, subfield FROM subtable WHERE ..... ) AS b 
ON a.id = b.subid 
WHERE ...
```

but I'm getting the syntax error.

How is the correct syntax for this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please move the `SET a.field=(a.field+b.subfield)` after `ON a.id = b.subid` and before `WHERE`

So, the query should look like this:

```
UPDATE table a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT subid, subfield FROM subtable WHERE ..... ) AS b 
ON a.id = b.subid 
SET a.field=(a.field+b.subfield) 
WHERE ...
```

Give it a Try !!!